# Call method from class of unknown name

Tags: php, logic

The title may be confusing, but I'm not sure how to word it otherwise. So I want to be able to initialize a class and call methods from it without knowing the class name before getting it from an array.

**What I want to do**

```
$modules = array(
    'Forums' => array(
            'class'=>'Forums',
            'classVar'=>'forum'
    )
);

        foreach($modules as $name => $module) if ($module['enabled']) {
            require_once('include/scripts/'.$module['link']);
            $$module['classVar'] = new $module['class'];
            $$module['classVar'] = $module['classVar'];
            global $$module['classVar'];
        }
```

However, I know that this is a roundabout way to accomplish this, and I need to know if there's an easier way, and if this is even logical.

The reason I want to do this is because what I'm working on will be able to accept modules, and I need to be able to get all of the stats from the modules and display them in the main admin panel, but there's no way to know if a module is enabled and running if I didn't create it. For instance, if someone created `module.php` that tracked how many times someone clicked a specific link, the software wouldn't natively know about it, and I need it to be able to get stats from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, you might be interested in the Singleton design pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern and http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html).

In this case you'd have a list of classes in your configuration array and call "getInstance()" when you actually want to do something with the actual module.

Also, have a look at the Factory pattern, it might be useful for your purposes as well.

Comment: Well, looking at this (unless I'm wrong) I would still need to know the variable that is equal to `new someClass;`

Comment: Not really. With singleton, you can just use `ClassName::getInstance()` or `$classRef::getInstance()` instead of storing the instance in a global variable (or passing it around). That, of course, assumes that you have module class name in your module configuration array.

Comment: (I mean that physically there WILL be an instance variable, but it'll be managed by the singleton itself - you, as a module consumer, don't need to care about it).

Comment: That, of course, is just a simplest possible implementation, assuming that you're not using a framework; if you're using Symfony, have a look at "tagged services"(http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html).

Comment: The singleton approach led me to my solution, thank you.